# How to add multiple <span> elements with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, text, append

I've a simple `<div>` element into which I want to `append()` multiple `<span>` elements, each of which with a different text, retrieved from an input field.

The problem is that only one `span` is added, and all subsequent ones are not.

```js
$('#add-tag').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let txt = $('#tag-text').val();
  const desc = (txt || '').trim();

  if (desc !== '') {
    const root = $('.tags-group');
    root.append("<a href='#' class='badge badge-primary'></a>").text(desc);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="tag-text" type="text" placeholder="Type some tag...">
    <button type="submit" id="add-tag">
      <i class="eos-icons">add</i>
      <span>Add</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="tags-group">
    <!-- Here we insert the added tags... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you append the new `<a>` element, then immediately overwrite the content of the parent element you just appended to with the text in `desc`.

To fix the issue, create the `a` element, set its text, then append it directly:

```js
const $root = $('.tags-group');

$('#add-tag').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let txt = $('#tag-text').val();
  const desc = (txt || '').trim();

  if (desc) {
    $('<a href="#" class="badge badge-primary"></a>').text(desc).appendTo($root);
  }
});
```

```css
a { display: block; } /* only for this demo */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="tag-text" type="text" placeholder="Type some tag...">
    <button type="submit" id="add-tag">
      <i class="eos-icons"></i>
      <span>Add</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="tags-group">
    <!-- Here we insert the added tags... -->
  </div>
</div>
```